# Web Service not accessible on Tomcat 7 - 404 error

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans, http-status-code-404

**Hi Friends
I have created a sample web service using netbeans 7.3. It works fine on localhost when running through tomcat linked with netbeans.**

**When I deploy it in webapps folder of the tomcat 7 on any standalone machine, it works fine too. BUT when we transfer the code from webapps to public_html folder of online linux server, I get 404 error.  please see the file. Online server has tomcat 7 which is linked through with Apache**

*web.xml*

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-     app_2_5.xsd">
<listener>
<listener-class>
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>EduCloudWS</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>EduCloudWS</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/EduCloudWS</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

*sun-jaxws.xml*

```
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
<endpoint implementation="com.educloud.ws.EduCloudWS" name="EduCloudWS" url-pattern="/EduCloudWS"/>
</endpoints>
```

I am trying to access by following links, both don't work and give a 404 error

- http://domainname.com/EduCloudWS
- http://domainname.xom/EduCloudWS/EduCloudWS

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you check the logs when you deploy it? May be the URLs are mapped with different context root. So check your logs to see how the URLs are mapped.